# Can I install fonts from CTAN using TeX Live Utility?

Tags: fonts, installing, mactex, ctan

I have the latest version of MacTeX installed, and want to add fonts from CTAN (or other packages) that are not part of the MacTeX distribution to my system. When I specify CTAN in TeX Live Utility as the repository to download a font from (e.g, http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/) I get an error:

> "Repository has a different TeX Live version ...  You need to switch
>   repositories in order to continue."

Clearly I'm doing something wrong. Can I use TeX Live Utility in this way to install and manage fonts that are not part of the MacTeX distribution? If not, what are my options?

Comment: If the packages are not part of TeXLive, then no, you can't use TeXLive Utility to install them. What fonts do you want to install?

Comment: @AlanMunn: URW Garamond for mathdesign.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't use `tlmgr` (or its front-end TeX Live Utility). There is a script called `getnonfreefonts` at http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/ that you have to download with the Terminal command

```
curl -O http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts
```

and then install with

```
sudo texlua install-getnonfreefonts
```

Then you can get direction on its use by

```
getnonfreefonts --help
```

For example, in order to install URW Garamond for all users you do

```
sudo getnonfreefonts-sys garamond
```

Installing fonts for one user only is not recommended.

Comment: *“Installing fonts for one user only is not recommended.”*  Why?

Comment: @morbusg Because one must remember to run manually `updmap` every time `tlmgr` updates some font related package. Using `updmap` instead of `updmap-sys` is a sure source of headaches.

Comment: @egreg: Does that mean that after running TeXLive Utility, [I need to rerun any and all other config tools](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47662/7844) I might have used outside of TeXLive (e.g., texhash or udmap)?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius No, the installation is permanent.

Comment: @egreg: What does the previous comment refer to then?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius The comment refers to using `getnonfreefonts` instead of `getnonfreefonts-sys` or installing other fonts for a single user.

Comment: I get a 404 with `curl`, but `wget` works.