# Installing font "Classico" on TexMac

Tags: fonts, installing

I'm currently trying to install the font Classico on a new Mac OS X 10.8.4 system using TexLive.

I followed this tutorial and managed each of the steps successfully:
http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/fonts/urw/classico/README

But when I try to use the font in pdflatex, it gives me lots of error messages like this one:

> ```
> ! Font OT1/uop/m/n/10.95=uopr7t at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
> ```

So what's the problem here? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47491/can-i-install-fonts-from-ctan-using-tex-live-utility/47504#47504%20this) can help. It contains the steps to install urw fonts. But if you're using a Mac you have Optima, from which this "Classico" clone was created. You can use Optima with xe(la)tex.

Comment: Perfect! Installing "getnonfreefonts" and using "sudo getnonfreefonts-sys classico" did it. Thank you!