# How to Use Boldface when Using the Package ebgaramond-maths

Tags: bold, ebgaramond

I am using the package `ebgaramond-maths` (see http://ctan.org/pkg/ebgaramond-maths).

Using this package, the boldface command `\textbf` does not actually put sentences in boldface. However, there are some words in the document I'm working on that really have to be put in boldface. It is perhaps useful to note that these words do not appear in math mode.

In the preamble I put (among other - irrelevant - things) the following:

```
\usepackage[lf]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\pdfmapfile{+EBGaramond-Maths.map}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
```

Then, my question is:

*How can I solve this? How do I put words in boldface using the package `ebgaramond-maths`?*

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you read the package documentation? `ebgaramond` by design does not include a bold weight, so if you absolutely need bold, it's probably not the best choice...

Comment: perhaps it's impossible.  the documentation for `ebgaramond` (in the `readme` file) says that these shapes are available: italic, small caps, italic small caps.  there's no mention of any bold.

Comment: It could be that it's not possible. However, I just need boldface a few times. So it would be a pity not to use ebgaramond just for these few instances... Thus, _if_ it would be possible in some way, I'd be glad to hear it!

Comment: I think it is intentional: at the time of Claude Garamond, no bold characters were carved, and this font has been designed to be the faithful replication of an historical specimen. You might try to use the bold version of `garamondx` but there perhaps would be some scaling to do, and it is not sure both fonts match perfectly. You would certainly also have to modify some `.fd` files, as medium weight is automatically substituted for boldface by the package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fake the boldface with the Garamond font provided by `mathdesign`; but, please, think twice before using boldface with Garamond.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lf]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
%\pdfmapfile{+EBGaramond-Maths.map} % not necessary on my system
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\fakebf}{\fontfamily{mdugm}\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbf}{\fakebf}

\begin{document}

This text is in EB Garamond,
with \textbf{fake boldface}.

\textbf{This text is not in EB Garamond}

Some math $a+b=\textbf{T}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! However, the line "\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbf}{\fakebf}" gives the following error: "!pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file ugmm8a.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font 
file for reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!" Do you know what might be the problem? Sorry, I am quite ignorant in these things.

Comment: @MehdiZ. It means you have an incomplete TeX distribution

Comment: Ok. Thanks. How do I make it into a complete TeX distribution?

Comment: FYI: I downloaded the MacTeX-2014 Distribution (see http://www.tug.org/mactex/). Still it doesn't work then. So how do I "complete" my TeX distribution?

Comment: Look for `pdftex.map` in the `log` file; what is the path of the file? It should be `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map`

Comment: It is. It literally says the following: `){/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}{EBGaramond-Maths.map} (./ebgaramond-maths.sty`

Comment: @MehdiZ. Did you recently run TeX Live Utility? It seems time to do it.

Comment: @egreg. (Thanks a lot for your help so far.) No, I hadn't! To be honest I had never even used that program. Now I've done it. I did all the updates, etc. Still, it does not work. The same error from above persists: `!pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file ugmm8a.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font 
file for reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`

Comment: @MehdiZ. See my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47491/can-i-install-fonts-from-ctan-using-tex-live-utility