# EB-Garamond fake boldface on figure labels

Tags: captions, ebgaramond

I am using [EB-Garamond Fake Boldface with Mathdesign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235400/how-to-use-boldface-when-using-the-package-ebgaramond-maths) to make get boldfaces. However, I cannot get the figure labels in boldface using the `\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}`. I think this is probably because the fake boldface will apply to `\textbf` only.

Is there any way I can change the \captionsetup to adapt the fake boldface for figure labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a new caption font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lf]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
%\pdfmapfile{+EBGaramond-Maths.map} % not necessary on my system
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\fakebf}{\fontfamily{mdugm}\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbf}{\fakebf}
\DeclareCaptionFont{fakebf}{\fakebf}

\captionsetup{labelfont=fakebf}

\begin{document}

This text is in EB Garamond,
with \textbf{fake boldface}.

\textbf{This text is not in EB Garamond}

Some math $a+b=\textbf{T}$

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
A FIGURE HERE

\caption{A caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But it looks like actors in Ben Hur wearing wristwatches.