# Understanding font maps / Fonts in vanilla TeXLive installation on Ubuntu

Tags: fonts, texlive, fontspec, ubuntu, kpathsea

I followed closely the instructions in this [tutorial](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/95373#95373) to install a fresh TeXLive on my Ubuntu system, including the fake package and the font cache instruction:

```
 sudo fc-cache -fsv
```

Still, I am unable to use the [Garamond](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/garamond/) font which is supposed to be part of TeXLive.

This is demonstrated by the following simple file:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\nobreakspace}{\leavevmode\nobreak\ } 
\begin{document}
\normalfont
The quick brown fox jumps over the sleazy dog.
\end{document}
```

Which fails to generate a PDF with the following error

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ugmr8a.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for rea
ding
```

Plain `latex` works just fine, but gain if I write `dvipdf myfile.dvi` I get the same error message:

```
dvips: ! Couldn't find font file ugmr8a.pfb
```

The `tfm` files seem to exist though:

```
find /usr/local/texlive/ -name "ugmr*"
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/mathdesign/mdugm/ugmr8a.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/mathdesign/mdugm/ugmri8a.tfm
```

Could the error be related to the instruction to remove Type 1 fonts in the tutorial?

[image]

I would greatly appreciate a direct answer solving this particular problem and/or a simple tutorial on how the KPS* and `updmap` work.

Comment: this link seems broken

Comment: Look at the extension: pdflatex doesn't complain about a .tfm but about a .pfb. The fonts are not part of texlive, but you can get them here http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/garamond

Comment: I forgot: you can also use getnonfreefonts to install the fonts; https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/

Comment: You *need* to use `getnonfreefonts` for the Garamond font used by `mathdesign`. You find instructions at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47491/can-i-install-fonts-from-ctan-using-tex-live-utility (the question is about Mac OS X, but the answer is for generic Unix).

Comment: @egreg: one can install them manually (I did it on miktex), but getnonfreefonts is naturally easier.

Comment: Use `getnonfreefonts-sys` - do NOT use `getnonfreefonts`. @egreg means `getnonfreefonts-sys` really, I think.

Comment: @cfr Yes, of course! http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47504/4427

Answer (score 2):

Your installation was correct. If you try other fonts, you would encounter no problems. You just were unlucky enough to try the Garamond font first. The KPSE* family and the `updmap` are not the issue here.

Apparently, the problem lies with the documentation at the LaTeX font catalog which [claims](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/garamond/) that Garamond is part of TeXLive.

Garamond is only partially included with TeXLive. The `.tfm` files are included. But `.tfm`, an acronym for the "TeX Font Metric", only provides the dimensions of the font, but not its contents. The actual content is found in `.pfb` files, an acronym for "Printer Font Binary", which is used for specifying the shapes of Adobe Type 1 fonts.

Now, the `.pfb` files are part of the Garamond package, as you can see by checking [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/urw-garamond). But, they are not part of Ubuntu installation, probably due to reasons of purity, i.e., free software and the such.

So, if you are an Ubuntu purist, you should find avoid Garamond. If you are just experimenting, then there are many other fonts around. If you really need Garamond on Ubuntu, the comments below the question may be able to provide a work around.